# How to post data to a controller method with Jquery Ajax that is in an external file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use post data to my database with ajax that I have in an external file.
I know this works in the view

```
    function SubmitClientInformationData() {
    var dataToSubmit = ClientInformationData();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action('AddClientInformation')",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSubmit),
        success: function (data) { },
        complete: function (e) {
        }
    });
}
```

But when I add this to the external JS file, it gets called but it never reaches my controller method.
I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609469/mvc-ajax-action-relative-to-current-controller/7609594#7609594)
and I tried what was mentioned in here, but to a button instead and it looks like this

```
<input id="btnSaveClientInfo" type="button" data-save-action-url="@Url.Action("AddClientInformation")" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

But it  never got to my method that I have in my controller for the view.

So in short, I have the ajax call in an external file and have a button in the view and when I click the button the data gets to my external file but I want to call my method that is in the view's controller to send the data to my database. Here is the basic of the method I am trying to call from the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddClientInformation(ClientInformation clientinformation)
{
    #region Initialization

    OQOE = new OQOEDAL();

    #endregion

    return View("Preferences");
}
```

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, I think I seen 2 errors, I'll double check.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error

Comment: Check if there is anything wrong with the resulting URL. `"@Url.Action('AddClientInformation')"` this value looks like this is for server processing.

Comment: That is why the error. Change that and put a proper URL you'll be fine.

Comment: this is the error
POST http://localhost:17508/Preferences/@Url.Action('AddClientInformation') 404 (Not Found),
I am not sure what you mean by using the proper url, are you meaning @Url.Action('Preferences/AddClientInformation')?

Comment: yes. exactly. when `@Url.Action('AddClientInformation')` this is in the asp page, the return value of the function will be in the location of URL. When you move this in side a JS file, it will not be processed by ASP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32037796/1479535 see this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will work only if you make the AJAX call from the view. If you want it to work from a JS file, you'll have to do something like the following -

Add the following to your view -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AddClientURLParam = {
    AddClientURL : '@Url.Action("AddClientInformation")'
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<Location of your JS File>"></script>
```

Make sure you reference your JS file below this `script` block and change the way you make the AJAX call to something like this -

```
function SubmitClientInformationData() {
    var dataToSubmit = ClientInformationData();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: AddClientURLParam.AddClientURL,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSubmit),
        success: function (data) { },
        complete: function (e) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I appreciate it, but is this only way to do this? Is there a way to do this without having the action passed from the view, but have it reside in the external file?

Comment: You can directly do - `/Preferences/AddClientInformation` from the JS file. Since you're using a .NET method to resolve the URL, it will be unavailable when you call it from the JS file. So the above solution is the best way to do it.